# Ubuntu Keyboard + Compiz Config + dconf Editor: Shortcut issues

Tags: 16.04

I'm trying to get Switch To Right Workspace be mapped to `<CTRL>+RIGHT`.

I'm having a hard time figuring out if which one of the programs settings are actually set in effect since you can set this feature in all three ways (Normal Ubuntu keyboard, Compiz Config & dconf Editor).

Is there some sort of run order for these programs?

Answer (score 1):

Well I figured it out. It had nothing to do with shortcuts. I have one 1 workspace set. Setting more of them resulted in the switcher working. Doh.